# Django: Count users used in model's ManyToMany

Tags: python, sql, django

Given a model:

```
class Workshop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

(User is django.contrib.auth.models.User)

Users can be in more than one Workshop:

- w1.participants = (u1, u2)
- w2.participants = (u2, u3)
- ...

I need to find:
1) Number of users participating in 1 workshop (u1, u3)
2) Number of users participating in 2 workshop (u2)
3) Number of users who don't participating in any workshop (u0)

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you try something to share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

1)

```
User.objects.annotate(workshop_count=Count('workshop')).filter(workshop_count=1).count()
```

2)

```
User.objects.annotate(workshop_count=Count('workshop')).filter(workshop_count=2).count()
```

3)

```
User.objects.filter(workshop__isnull=True).count()
```

[More info in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
workshop_user_dict = {}
user_objects = User.objects.all()
for user in user_objects:
     workshops_count = user.workshop_set.all().count()
     if not workshops_count in workshop_user_dict:
         workshop_user_dict[workshops_count] = []
     workshop_user_dict[workshops_count].append(user)


for key, list in workshop_user_dict.items():
    print 'There are ' + str(len(list)) + ' users that are participating in ' + str(key) +  ' workshops'
```

Comment: Thanks for the try but this is not helping.
I'm looking for an output of the form:
`34 users participating in 1 workshop.
14 users participating in 2 workshops.
60 users are not participating in any workshop.`

Comment: @user2262400 Updated answer to do what you want. :) Let me know if it works

Comment: Again, thank you! I didn't test it though. My question was how to get the number directly from the DB without iterating over objects and with minimum DB calls. Your solution might be good for small systems without many users.